# Asynchronously loading image into autolayout UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, autolayout

I've searched SO and have not seen an answer specifically for Autolayout.

I have a UITableViewCell using Autolayout. The UIImageView is constrained to have its edges 12 pt from Cell edges and the trailing edge of the Label.

[image: UITableViewCell]

Images are retrieved asynchronously and assigned to the UIImageView's image property.

```
[self downloadImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrlString] completionBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, UIImage *image) {
  if (succeeded) {
    weakSelf.newsImageView.image = image;
    // [weakSelf.contentView layoutIfNeeded];
  }
}];
```

If there is a blank placeholder image assigned to the image of the cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath, then the asynchronously retrieved image is loaded and visible. If the blank placeholder assignment is commented out, the asynchronously retrieved image never appears.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    SCTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tableCellIdentifier];
    //    cell.newsImageView.image = _blankImage;
    return cell;
}
```

I tried layoutIfNeeded (commented out above) and updateConstraintsIfNeeded to see if the image would appear but it did not work. So for now I've been putting a blank image there first, which seems like a hack, and wouldn't be flexible if relying on intrinsic content size of images who's sizes could be different. Are the constraints being optimized out of existence when the first layout occurs? Anyone know what's going on and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling: `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize` on your `UIImageView` in the completion handler. This should force the auto layout system to recalculate the view intrinsic size. Possibly, you could also need calling `updateConstraintsIfNeeded` after that (but try first without).

If this does not work and your `UIImageView`s have a known size, you could try subclassing `UIImageView` and override the `-intrinsicContentSize` method. Return the known size from it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I gave invalidateIntrinsicContentSize and updateConstraintsIfNeeded a try but no luck. I log intrinsicContentSize of the UIImageView before and after the async handler and strangely, for both the case with transparent placeholder image and without, it is {100, 100} before and {320, 320} after retrieval. I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: Turns out it was something of an error in the nib file. Appreciate the advice regardless. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the nib somehow had two outlets referring to the same UIImageView element. One outlet didn't exist in code, yet still linked in the nib UI. Must have been a mishap in refactoring, but removing it fixes it.